# Creating objects in WPF at runtime using MVVM

Tags: wpf

I'm creating a app in WPF using MVVM pattern.

I need to present a set of information read from the database in the form of rectangles on the screen, that is, each record in the database correspond to a rectangle on the screen in the following format:

```
[register 1]
[register 2]
[register n]
```

Where **[register ...]** is a rectangle with text inside on the screen.

Edit: I also have the following scenario:

```
[       register 1      ]
[       register 2      ]
[register 3] [register 4]
[register 5] [register 6]
[       register n      ]
```

What better way to accomplish this implementation considering that my data is in a view-model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `ListView` with a custom `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: Hi Felice, thanks for replying! This works great! But I have a problem: I need to present on the same line two records as shown in the above edit, how to do this with list view? is it possible?

Comment: You can use a lIstBox in this case, and customize the ItemsPanelTemplate to be an uniform grid with two columns.